# C# WinForm : Reload form after submit another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm newbie of winform. I have opened form2 form a linklabel in form1 using :

```
private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    FrmAddMov frmAddMov = new FrmAddMov();
    if(frmAddMov.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        //or
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I thought form1 will reload after I submit form2, but not. Please tell me the right way to do it. Thanks a lot, and sorry if my english is too bad.

Comment: You should add `this.DialogResoult = DialogResult.OK` at the end of your submitting method.

Comment: Invalidate/Refresh cause control to redraw. If you need update some data properties - well, write code to set properties

Comment: It is not obvious how "reload" is supposed to work.  You are showing a dialog to get info from the user, when you don't use it then it isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: But first  lets define what really happens? "It's not reloading" not a actual question. Is `frmAddMov.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK` is `false` or it's `true`, but your form is not reloading? Please provide some details.

Comment: I have added this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK at the end of my submitting method, and frmAddMov.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK it's true, but my form still not reloading.

Comment: @MinhHoàngCao Please put all code refering to frmAddMov inside a using statement, you will get into troubles later if  you dont learn that now. Check out my answer for an example on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gentleman's answer will work, but it can be improved.
When showing a form using `ShowDialog`than it is best practice to dispose of that form, and the easiest way to do that is by the `using` statement

```
private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    using (FrmAddMov frmAddMov = new FrmAddMov())
    {
        if (frmAddMov.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           FormLoad();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you are always 100% sure that all resources for frmAddMov will be cleaned up.

Comment: This is a must for any object that derives from IDisposable.

Comment: @Kevbo I cannot agree more. Its sad however to see again someone skipping best practices when learning dotnet... Its because of that I did not upvote the answer allthough it is correct in answering the OP

Comment: Thanks GuidoG, I got this.

Comment: @GuidoG  I gave your answer the upvote to keep it near the top.  Little things like this can make a big difference to beginners.

Comment: @Kevbo Thanks, it is indeed very little change in code but does makes big difference I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Move everything in your form load event to a method say FormLoad. You may want to add few other statements which you are expecting form reload will do for you. Call this method when your 2nd form closes.

Something like this

```
private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrmAddMov frmAddMov = new FrmAddMov();
        if(frmAddMov.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           FormLoad();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you put your frmAddMov inside a `using`it would be perfect. I know it has nothing to do with the question but its better to learn new programmers how to use best practice